# How can I determine where an NPM's transitive dependency is coming from?

Tags: npm

I'm trying to `npm install` a package, but it's failing to install due to a missing transitive dependency.

(I don't think the details are important, but we're proxying to an Nexus NPM registry, which didn't support [scoped modules](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/scoped-packages) at the time. One of our dependency's dependencies is trying to pull down the `@bahmutov/parse-github-repo-url` module, and we get a 404.)

In my `npm-debug.log` I see the 404 from our registry:

```
404 - Path /@bahmutov/parse-github-repo-url not found in group repository</title>
```

But I can't tell which dependency is trying to pull it down.

Normally I'd run `npm ls [package-name]` but this doesn't work for a project with an empty `node_modules` folder, which is what's going on here.

We're using npm3, which has a flat dependency tree, so I can't just open up the partially-hydrated `node_modules` folder and see where things get laid down.

Is there a way to inspect a `package.json` file and determine the calculated dependency tree without relying on `npm install` to succeed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[npm-remote-ls](https://github.com/npm/npm-remote-ls) looks like it might give you a reasonable answer!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [npm-ls](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-ls), via the command `npm ls`.

By default, this shows only the immediate dependencies (first level of depth) of the root project.

But you an show all dependency levels by specifying a depth of `-all`:

```
npm ls --all
```

Or you could use the `depth` flag to specify the level of depth you want to see:

```
npn ls --depth=2
```